# It is correct to say "on level" or "at level"?

Tags: prepositions

Tell me please, how it is correct to say:

> "He knows English **at** basic level"

or:

> "He knows English **on** basic level"?

Comment: "at basic level" is educational jargon, not how the "man in the street" would say it.  The lay person would say "He knows basic English" or "He has a basic command of English".

Comment: It is very important to understand that in English, we use a _determiner_ before a noun. This can be a _quantifier_ like "many", or an _article_ like "a" or "the", or a _possessive_ like "their"; there are many kinds, but in either of your sentences, _level_ needs one. See [**this link.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual wording is

> He knows English at a basic level.

Both of your wordings are easily understood (and difficult to misunderstand), but are not those of a native English speaker.

Comment: Are you a native English speaker? What does "wording" mean? I have never seen such form for "word".

Comment: @Cherry "Wording" and "phrasing" are both very commonly used English words. An easy way to learn what "wording" means is to look it up in an English language dictionary. There are dozens of dictionaries available online.

Comment: @Cherry - to continue that previous comment, [here is a link](https://www.wordnik.com/words/wording) to an entry for _wording_ in an online dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

I would use *at* and include an indefinite article:

> He knows English at a basic level.

I don't think I'd argue that *on* is wrong. In fact, you can find instances where [both prepositions are used in published works](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+a+basic+level%2Con+a+basic+level%2Cat+an+advanced+level%2Con+an+advanced+level&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).